# What esc_ to use to validate this?

Tags: php, validation

I tired esc_url but it doesn't work.

```
if ( $power_by ) { ?>
            <div class="sponsor-credits">
                <span class="sponsor-credits__label">Powered by </span>
                <span class="sponsor-credits__sponsor">
                    <?php
                    if ( $sponsor_link ) {
                        printf(
                            '<a href="%1$s" class="sponsor-credits__link" target="_blank" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                            esc_url( $sponsor_link ),
                            esc_attr( $sponsor_name ),
                            $power_by
                        );
```

$power_by is this

```
$power_by     = '<img class="sponsor-credits__logo" src="' . esc_url( $sponsor_logo[0] ) . '">';
```

Comment: Why do you use a temporary variable? Don't assemble HTML for use later on like that

Answer (score 0):

esc_url is the correct function to escape links -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url - if it's not working correctly then double check the actual output of your variables to make sure they are in fact links.

But selling links in your themes via "sponsored" links is not something I would ever recommend anyone doing which from the code it looks like you are doing. "Powered by" should be followed by "WordPress". And maybe even "developed by Your Name" - but selling links in themes just makes them look spammy and untrustworthy (my 2 cents).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good.

Your `printf` statement makes `$power_by` become the content of an anchor `<a>` element. No [`esc_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) escaping needed here, since `$power_by` contains valid HTML code.

The url attribute withing `$power_by` should be escaped with [`esc_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/), which escapes illegal characters but also filters the url protocoll etc.